# Writing and reading between threads with Android Realm

Tags: android, multithreading, realm

I'm performing some investigation of `Realm` threading and encountered issue.

In this simple example I have 2 `Thread` objects, one for writing and second one for reading. The reader `Thread` gets count of written objects always as 0, but inside writer scope the `size()` for items in DB is correct. When I relaunch app, the reader gets the first count ok before any insertions.

```
Thread writer = new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (mRunning) {
            try {
                Realm r = Realm.getInstance(context, "test_db");
                r.beginTransaction();

                TestData data = r.createObject(TestData.class);

                r.commitTransaction();

                Logger.e("WRITER THREAD COUNT: " + 
                    r.where(TestData.class).findAll().size());

                sleep(LATENCY);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};

writer.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
writer.start();

Thread reader = new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (mRunning) {
            try {
                Logger.e("READING THREAD COUNT: " + Realm.getInstance(context,
                        "test_db").where(TestData.class).findAll().size());

                sleep(LATENCY);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};

reader.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
reader.start();
```

Is there something needed to do for this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Emanuele from Realm here.

What you are describing is expected behavior :) Since the reader thread doesn't have a `Looper`, it has no way to receive notifications from the reader thread and will never update unless you manually execute a `refresh`.

In out repo we have several examples (not to mention unit tests) using threads with and without `Looper`, illustrating the current best practices.

Comment: Technically `.refresh()` doesn't exist anymore, but you can emulate a "looper thread" auto-update using [`waitForChange()/stopWaitForChange()`](https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/8786ec511f7e1f47673935a26f568106)