# Realm with RxAndroid not picking up latest data changes

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, realm

I am using Realm with RxAndroid. i am having this strange issue where realm is not picking up the latest modification done on DB.

There are 2 methods that i am using.

```
Observable<Integer> save(Bitmap bitmap).
Observable<Integer> getImageList(Context applicationContext).
```

Like this

```
   Activity 1
   getImageList(applicationContext)
   button click -> Activity 2
                      save(bitmap)
                      finish()  

   getImageList(applicationContext)
```

This method "save" basically adds a newly created model into RealmList.

```
private Observable<Integer> save(Bitmap bitmap) {
return Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>) subscriber -> {
    --------------------------------------
    -----Various file creation stuff------
    --------------------------------------

     UserImagesModel model = realm
                    .where(UserImagesModel.class)
                    .findFirst();


    //ImageModel class extends RealmObject 
    ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();

    realm.beginTransaction();
    //realm object must be Edited inside transaction
    model.getResponse().add(0, imageModel);
    realm.commitTransaction();

    realm.close();
    subscriber.onNext(1);
    subscriber.onCompleted();
 }
}
```

Ans this method fetches saved list.

```
public Observable<Integer> getImageList(Context applicationContext) {
    return Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>) subscriber -> {
        AppUtils.logD("User image observable instance " + this);
        UserImagesModel model;
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(applicationContext);
        model = realm.where(UserImagesModel.class).findFirst();
          ^
  This model doesn't replicate data added in save call

        ------------------------------------------------
        ----Various validation and service calls.-------
        ------------------------------------------------

        subscriber.onCompleted();
        realm.close();
    });
 }
}
```

As i mentioned in code, UserImageModel that i get from Realm doesn't replicate changes i made in save method.

the problem occurs when i call getImageList method **second time**. also when i print this.toString inside Observable.create it prints same object that was returned first time.

So i believe this issue seems to be with the way i am using RxAndroid. can anyone tell me what i am missing? and how can i resolve it?

**UPDATE :**

After few tests i realized that this.toString inside Observable.create is actually points to parent object as i have used lamda expression so that is not seems to be the issue and now i am back to square one ;(

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, this is expected behavior of Realm. as i was subscribing those observables on IO threads which doesn't have Looper.

Op [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134130/writing-and-reading-between-threads-with-android-realm) has similar issue. answer explains the case.